# How can I make Ubuntu only boot from SSD?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have two drives and I want it so that the ssd drive is only for Ubuntu boot. Nothing saved on it, not even system files just have it boot from ssd and I have a hdd to put storage and any other stuff. how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

2 Options:

Option One:

I would remove the HDD, install Ubuntu on the SSD, and once the installation is done, connect the HDD again.  Open Disks from Dash, and partition and format the HDD **if needed**.

Image below is instructional only

[image]

Option Two:

Now if you want to have `/home` on the HDD, then leave the drive connected, and choose Something else, and assign `/home` to the HDD, or maybe `/data`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when you install ubuntu, choose "somehing else" install ubuntu, "/" on the ssd and "/home" on the hhd, you can look this link http://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/
it show you how to do to other partition, but it work too for other driver,